# jQuery question regarding if statement and position moving

Tags: jquery, html, css, syntax, jquery-animate

I'm trying to write a program where basically the user clicks on an image and the image will then move to the right by 25px. The image moves when I click on it, but I tried to add a piece of code which makes the image return to the left of the window when it passes the right side of the window. I've tried using an If statement in the animation's procedure but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have:

```
$('#image').click(function() {
$(this).animate({
   left: '+=155',
function() {
    if ($(this).left > $(document).width)  {
 $(this).left = 0
  }
   };

    });
```

});

---

Am I using the wrong syntax or is my function wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this...

```
$('#image').click(function() {

     $(this).animate({
            left: '+=155',
            function() {
                if ($(this).offset().left > $(document).width)  {
                   $(this).css({ left: 0 });
                }


       });
});
```

Though really it'd be better off adding the shift pixels to the original `left` first, and making sure that doesn't exceed the width. In that case, `return false` and don't move the element at all.

You probably also want to add the width of `#image` to the offset before you calculate it, otherwise it won't trigger it has exceeded until the far left of the element has exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your duration?

Try this,

```
$('#image').click(function() {
     $(this).animate(
            {
               left: '+=155'
            },
            5000,
            function() {
                if ($(this).left > $(document).width)  {
                $(this).left = 0
                }    
       );
});
```